# Potatoes in bread? How to estimate potatoes needed?

Tags: baking, potatoes

Just found out that adding potato to a bread recipe can make it softer and more moist. I'd like to experiment with this. If I were following a recipe that didn't include potatoes, how could I modify it to include potatoes? Do the potatoes need to be a certain percentage of the flour? Do I add more liquids along with the potato? Do I remove some flour and replace with potatoes?

Also, will potato flakes work as well?

Comment: I don't know how to modify an existing bread recipe, so I'll just offer this as a comment. Potato Bread is a very common thing; here's a good [recipe](http://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/potato-bread-recipe). Since the recipe calls for mashed potatoes, you could certainly use flakes that you have made into mashed potatoes. Although, I wouldn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to be careful when trying to modify an existing non-potato recipe.

Potatoes, like any other agricultural product, have a variable amount of starch and water. Some are big, some are small, etc, so it's hard to tell just how much flour and/or water you'd want to replace in an existing recipe without doing some serious lab-testing or trying to remove all the water somehow.

**The Non-risky method:**
Look for published recipes that already have potato added:

http://www.thefreshloaf.com/search/node/Potato

**The Experimental Method**
Take a recipe you like that could use a bit more moistness. Throw in a cup of baked potato. Remove a half-cup of flour and 1/4 cup of whatever liquid you're using.  You can also try using Potato flour:

http://www.bobsredmill.com/potato-flour.html

Bake that loaf and see what happens. Adjust the variables as necessary, and try it again, carefully documenting what worked and what didn't. If you develop something that you like, publish it so the rest of us can enjoy!

Comment: I like the idea of replacing the flour with potato flour. However, are there any concerns regarding the effects on the dough (e.g. gluten formation, etc.)?

Comment: @CookingNewbie You can't just swap them out. There is no gluten in potato flour, to replace wheat flour with potato flour in bread would take a lot of expert tweaking.

Comment: You can also buy wheat gluten to supplement the lack in the potato flour.  Again, it comes down to experimentation - either you do try a couple different things to see what works, or use the results of someone's else's experiments.

Comment: @CookingNewbie On the recipe I linked to above, this is in the comments,"Nessa from Japan
We love potato bread but me and my son we have celiac dicease now can we use the gluten free flour to make the potato bread?/////
This will take some experimentation, Nessa. Moving a recipe from wheat based to GF means you'll use the same amount of GF flour, and 1/4 teaspoon xanthan per cup of flour. We'd love to hear your results. Happy GF Baking! Irene@KAF"

Comment: The GF flour they're referring to is this one: http://www.kingarthurflour.com/shop/items/gluten-free-multi-purpose-flour

Answer (score 4):

I usually add about 2 tablespoons of mashed potatoes to my bread recipes (3 cups of flour).  I haven't tried it with potato flakes or potato flour. If you put too much the dough will be very sticky and the bread dense

Answer (score 2):

One large or 2 small potatoes for 1 kg flour, cooked and shredded. 3 3/4 cup of water for heavier Dark Rye/Whole Wheat/white flour combo :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not only will potato flakes work, it's a comparatively good use for them.

I really don't find it all that difficult to wing it - my usual approach of choose loaf size by amount of liquid, mix in non-flour things early, and stop adding flour when it's dough works fine here. If adding potatoes rather than flakes, they are more or less part of the liquid. If using flakes, don't go crazy - use (no more than) about enough flakes to make about as much mashed potatoes as the amount of liquid you are using.

Also, pay attention to results and adjust as needed (that's part of experimenting.)

Answer (score 0):

I use a 5 minute bread recipe which is two tablespoons of yeast, two tablespoons of salt, four cups of water, and eight cups of flour. I like to add sweet potato to my bread, and I use it as liquid, so I use one cup of mashed sweet potatoes and three cups of water and it turns out perfectly; very sweet and moist.