# If I use instant mashed potatoes for my potato bread, what do I iuse to replace 1-3/4 cup potato water?

Tags: substitutions

I am making potato bread. I want to use instant mashed potatoes. The recipe calls for 1-3/4 cups potato water. Is there a liquid substitution for the potato water?

Comment: Related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46026/effect-of-potato-water-on-bread-early-experiment-results

Answer (score 3):

Sorry if this comes over a little curt…

> Is there a liquid substitution for the potato water?

Water. 1:1 ratio.
Check for seasoning.

It won't taste like potato water, but then again instant mash doesn't taste like potato, so it won't really hurt overall.

Comment: The problem with this recommendation is that the starch in the potato water is part of what makes potato breads rise, since it gives the yeast a big boost.

Comment: @FuzzyChef - my main concern is really that instant mash is in itself no substitute for fresh, so any slight discrepancy is probably moot anyway.

Comment: I have a bread recipe somewhere that doesn't use the potatoes, just the starch-water.  It makes a huge difference in the rise and texture of the final bread.  I'm sure you're right about the mash texture as well.

Comment: A bit of corn starch (neutral flavor) or if you have it potato starch dissolved in the water would likely do the rise boost, but how much to add would be complete guesswork to me.